# Adding Admob ads to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, admob, ads

This is the original code. I am a beginner in iOS development, how should I modify the code such that Admob ads will be loaded at the bottom of tableview? I tried to follow the tutorial from http://jmsliu.com/1207/add-google-admob-in-ios-apps.html , but can't get it to work.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.prefixArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSDictionary *d = self.prefixArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = d[kMDTitleKey];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSDictionary *d = self.prefixArray[indexPath.row];
    NSInteger entryID = [d[kMDIdentifierKey] integerValue];
    self.searchBar.text = d[kMDTitleKey];
    [self.db fetchDefinitionsWithID:entryID callback:^(NSDictionary *response) {
        NSString *HTML = [self.HTMLRenderer renderHTML:response];
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:HTML baseURL:nil];
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you share uses the `UITableView`'s title `header` to show an ad. Probably that's not a good idea since you'll probably would need to use those headers for your own purposes.

I understand you want to put ads at the bottom of the screen. In that case it would be a good idea to use an `UIView` below `UITableView`. In that case you'll need to change your `UITableViewController` for an `UIViewController` to be able to do that.

If you want to add the add at the bottom of the `UITableView` you should think of it as the cell N+1 (being N the size of `self.prefixArray`) and update your table callbacks to handle the special case correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the advert view as the footerview for the tableview. Implement

> - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section

where you will create the advert view and return it as the footer view

dont put the advert view inside a cell, as it will be dequeued and its just the incorrect place for it.

Comment: I ran into this problem when trying to put the ads in footerview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158315/admob-ads-not-appear-in-footer-of-uitableview-when-keyboard-is-shown