# iOS Native AdMob

Tags: ios, swift, admob, banner

Trying to show Google Ad in **UITablewViewCell** using the [Native Google Ad documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native/start). But, I kept getting

```
Failed Ad Request:  Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show.}
```

This is my configuration:

I need to display customised Ads at the 3rd row of the table view.

**GoogleAdBannerView.swift**
    import UIKit
    import GoogleMobileAds

```
class GoogleAdBannerView: GADUnifiedNativeAdView {

    let modMediaView: GADMediaView = {
        let mediaView = GADMediaView()
        mediaView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return mediaView
    }()

    let bannerImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageview = UIImageView()
        imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageview
    }()

    let adTitle: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.mySFMedium(ofSize: 16)
        label.textColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.87)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let refreshBtn: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Refresh", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        btn.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.85, green:0.85, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setupViews()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {

        mediaView = modMediaView
        iconView = bannerImageView
        headlineView = adTitle

        addSubview(mediaView!)
        addSubview(iconView!)
        addSubview(headlineView!)
        addSubview(refreshBtn)

        mediaView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
        mediaView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
        mediaView?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        mediaView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true

        iconView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        iconView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        iconView?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        iconView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mediaView!.bottomAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true

        headlineView?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView!.rightAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        headlineView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView!.topAnchor).isActive = true
        headlineView?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

        refreshBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        refreshBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
        refreshBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 2/3, constant: -32).isActive = true
        refreshBtn.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    }
}
```

The table view cell:

**FieldListLiteAdCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class FieldListLiteAdCell: UITableViewCell, GADUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate {

    let mainView: GoogleAdBannerView = {
        let view = GoogleAdBannerView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    var controller: FieldListView? {
        didSet {
            if let _ = controller {
                fetchAds()
            }
        }
    }
    var adLoader: GADAdLoader!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.selectionStyle = .none

        addSubview(mainView)

        mainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.refreshBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshFieldAds(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        fetchAds()
    }

    @IBAction func refreshFieldAds(_ sender: UIButton) {
        fetchAds()
    }

    private func fetchAds() {

        adLoader = GADAdLoader(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511", rootViewController: controller, adTypes: [GADAdLoaderAdType.unifiedNative], options: nil)
        adLoader.delegate = self

        let adRequest = GADRequest()
        adRequest.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        adLoader.load(adRequest)
//        adLoader.load(GADRequest())
    }

    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        mainView.nativeAd = nativeAd
        nativeAd.delegate = self

        print("Ad has been received.")

        mainView.mediaView?.mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent

        (mainView.iconView as? UIImageView)?.image = nativeAd.icon?.image

        (mainView.headlineView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.headline
    }

    func adLoaderDidFinishLoading(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader) {
    }

    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("Failed Ad Request: ", error)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// MARK: - GADUnifiedNativeAdDelegate implementation
extension FieldListLiteAdCell: GADUnifiedNativeAdDelegate {

    func nativeAdDidRecordClick(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdDidRecordImpression(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdWillPresentScreen(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdWillDismissScreen(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdDidDismissScreen(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdWillLeaveApplication(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Tried multiple **App Unit ID**, created multiple accounts, waited for more than 2hrs as suggested by some **StackOverflow** answers. Ensured device ID is added to the request.

**Edit 1**

Someone marked the question as possible duplicate, with an un-verified suggestion. I had to make a sample app that implement this same logic and it's working fine.

I've reviewed the `Info.plist` file to ensure `Allow Arbitrary Loads` is set to `YES`. I'm yet to identify the reason behind the error.

[Sample GoogleAd Native Implementation](https://github.com/tonespy/googlead-tableview-cell-sample)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Admob ads to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563670/adding-admob-ads-to-uitableview)

Comment: `UITableViewCell` is not a view controller.  And you should display an ad with table view's header or footer.

Comment: @ElTomato 

-- The post is 3years old 

-- There was no answer to the question 

– You didn't try to replicate it, or verify if the suggestion made in the post is accurate or not.

-- Did a sample implementation for you to see here. And, yes, it works fine. https://github.com/tonespy/googlead-tableview-cell-sample

-- And, I am still seeing the error in the existing codebase I am handling. Which means the issue is being triggered by something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I wasn't doing anything wrong.

Commenting out the app-wide `UserAgent` modification done when app is initialised in app's delegate made the `Google Ad Mod` work fine.

My `UserAgent` looks like this:

`UserAgent: iOS-CompanyName/versionNumber`.

I don't know why my custom user agent is preventing me from being able to get `Ads` though.